# Getting Allowed memory size error on sample data deployment magento2

Tags: magento2, sample-data

I am Trying to install sample data on xampp server using below command
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
And i am getting error like this

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento v2.0\vendor\composer\composer\src\Composer\ Json\Json File.php on line 259

can any one help me?

Comment: You might need to add RAM to your server.

Comment: You might need to add RAM to your server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 2 solution for that:

*Option 1 - Permanent Solution*

change php.ini to increase `memory_limit` value on global level

```
memory_limit = 768M
```

**Or** You can also change in .htaccess file.

```
php_value memory_limit 768M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

*Option 2 - Temporary Solution*

quick solution add memory size in the command :

```
php -dmemory_limit=768M php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

change 768M to what you want

Comment: last command: php -dmemory_limit=768M && php bin/magento sampledata:deploy

Answer (score 1):

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

$ php --ini

Loaded Configuration File:  /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/conf/php.ini

$ nano /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/conf/php.ini

change the memory_limit there and that's it!