# Readiness check ignores memory limit

Tags: magento2, php, centos

CentOs 7 with php 5.6.26 and Plesk 12.2

[php.ini]

```
Memory_limit 2G
```

phpinfo() shows memory_limit of 2G.
Readyness check still says limit is set to 128M, so I did a reboot and performed an cache:clean and flush on magento, still same result.

I came accross the .htaccess memory_limit, increased it there as well, and repeatet steps above, doesnt work out.

Any suggestions? Do I miss something here?

Comment: Check this answer : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140600/getting-allowed-memory-size-error-on-sample-data-deployment-magento2

Comment: You're probably modifying the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

Official doc here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_php-set.html#trouble-php-memory

The important bit is to run: php --ini in a console and look for a line with  something like "Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php.ini". That's the file you need to edit, as it can be different from the one the webserver loads.

Comment: Note: your command line php and the php version your actual server is using can vary. Type `which php` to see the path your terminal is referencing for comparison