# Your current PHP memory limit is 128M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more

Tags: magento2, php, xampp

**Your current PHP memory limit is 128M. Magento 2 requires it to be set to 756M or more.** As a user with root privileges, edit your php.ini file to increase memory_limit. (The command php --ini tells you where it is located.) After that, restart your web server and try again.

i am trying the above but its not working for me .can anyone help me how to solve this ?

Comment: Apply changes in `php.ini` Apache

Comment: Find which php.ini your system is using. Open the file with text editor and search for memory_limit, Increase the value from 128M to 756M or more, save the php.ini file. Restart the web server and you should ready to go.

Comment: i did this already but its not working .after restarting again showing the same error.

Comment: @Ashish Which is your Webserver? Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Apache is my Webserver.

Comment: On Magento Root `index.php` `echo ini_get('memory_limit')`

Comment: This can help you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/140602/51548

Answer (score 0):

You maybe applied the changes in the wrong `php.ini` (since there's so many of them, especially in an old system ...)

Try finding the correct one as shown here [magento 2.1 Doc PHP Settings](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html)

> To find the PHP configuration file, php.ini:
>
> To find the web server configuration, run a phpinfo.php file in your web browser and look for the Loaded Configuration File as follows

or add `phpinfo()` function in the index.php like :

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point ...
 */

phpinfo(); die;

try {
   require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
}
```

you can try looking for memory limit there.